# How to delete duplicates in the NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I accessed the Data from sqlite file as NSMutableArray[model_Array] in which I have duplicates info [two/three] so i wanna delete that, I tried to assign the MutableArray to another NSMutableArray[allItems] by two different idea given below

```
AppDelegate *readTheDatabase = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:readTheDatabase.model_Array];  
NSSet *uniqueItems; 
uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:allItems];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in allItems)
    if (![uniqueItems containsObject:item])
        [uniqueItems addObject:item];
```

---

but it is unable to delete the duplicate data. please anyone help and suggest me to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So obviously the duplicate data is not exactly the same (as returned by `isEqualTo:`). Tell us more about your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objects within the array are obviously not returning true for the `isEqual:` method.

What kind of object does the array contain?

I assume it's some custom model class that represents the data in the database.

You should look up the documentation for `NSObject` and the `isEqual:` and `hash:` methods.

You will learn how to express when two objects are equal, which is how `NSArray` and `NSSet` etc determine whether objects are already contained within the collection.

Comment: yeah, It has custom class representing data of database.

Answer (score 1):

if you get duplicates from a database query, i would suggest to reformulate the query so it does not yield duplicates. ie. use [`SELECT DISTINCT ...`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct) instead of `SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NSSet` then make it to `NSArray` - otherwise, it will lead to a crash because it would be in `NSSet`, not `NSSArray`.

```
NSSet *uniqueItems= [NSSet setWithArray:YourArray];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[uniqueItems allObjects]]; 

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"The Given Array is %@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Good luck, it is very simple to do .......

Comment: What is the use of UniqueItems? and what is cleanedArray?

Comment: if you want sort then you could use NSSortDescriptor